# Existence of solutions to DLP and Primitive roots mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, primitive-roots

Discrete log problem - finding $x \ge 0$ for prime $p$ , generator $g>0$ and $h>0$ such that:

$$g^x \cong h \pmod{p}$$

Define $G$ as the group generated by all values of $g^x \pmod{p}$. Eg $G=${2,3,4}

My understanding is that if $h$ is in $G$ then solutions to the DLP exist.

**Question:**

Where solutions exist, does this mean that one does not need to check if $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$?

**Answer (based on comments)**

I don't believe one needs to check for primitive roots when solutions exist for the DLP

Comment: Read a bit about DLP and primitive roots, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52545/primitive-root-and-discrete-logarithm). If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, then by definition $g^x\equiv h \bmod p$ is always uniquely solvable for $h\in G$.

Comment: @dietrichburde I've read the linked question and answers. From your point, is the converse true?

Comment: The converse need not be true in general, of course. Just take $h=e$. Then $x=0$ is a solution, but $g$ need not be a primitive root.

Comment: Is $e$ the identity element & in this case has to be 1 since $g^0 = 1$?